# How to delete IPSEC VPN tunnel from Fortigate 60

Tags: vpn, ipsec, fortinet

I have had a IPSEC connection setup between two firewalls. Now I want to remove the tunnel in my firewall, a "Fortigate 60".

There are two phases, "Phase 1" and "Phase 2" for each IPSEC connection. I can delete the "Phase 2" entry by clicking the trashcan icon (in the web interface), but there is not such icon for "Phase 1". Is it possible to delete that?

When I look at the log it alerts about this tunnel not working (after deleting "Phase 2") and it would be nice not ta have loads of such events in the log.

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you can't delete something in the FortiGate, there usually is a reference to that object somewhere. Normally the references are easy to track as they appear on the UI adjacent to the object.

Two notable exceptions:
* A bug did exist in the past (an old version) where the delete button on the phase object wouldn't work
* Chrome browser doesn't always refresh that condition (not sure if a Chrome or Fortinet issue). Refreshing the sessions; close/reopen; empty cache or whatever works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I had some references under "Firewall" to the VPN. After deleting them I could also delete the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

goto network-->static routes
del vpn static routes first